# Где взять все коды клавиш относительно символов раскладки разных стран мира?

Tags: клавиатура, unicode, key

Мне важно знать к какой клавише, а именно с каким символом на ней тот или иной код относится.
Например: код:81 это английская Q, русская Й, сербская Љ.
Если я правильно понял как это работает.

У меня это не будет привязано к раскладке системы, я хочу знать заранее, например создав кучку словарей или типо того, умнее не придумал.

Все таблицы что я видел включают только английский, есть ли какая-нибудь общая база или сводная таблица я не знаю.

Не охота самому подбирать каждый символ на каждом языке.

Comment: https://kbdlayout.info/

Comment: Простите за нескромный вопрос, а почему вы не хотите привязываться к раскладке системы?